# SharePoint 2013 On-Prem - 2013 Workflows (Designer) SOMETIMES not starting automatically

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

So I have workflows created on several different lists built using SP Designer 2013 on the 2013 workflow platform. They are set to run when an item is created, and 90% of the time, they do.

However, there's that 10% of the time where they simply do not start. Click the item and checking the workflow log, it shows the workflow never even ran.

Why would this be? I can't find a pattern or commonality between the instances.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what's happening here, I'd check the ULS logs when the items were added, maybe there's a clue there.

Were the items which didn't trigger the workflow created by an account acting as System? System accounts won't trigger workflows.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No they were not triggered by System Account, the initiator is always an actual user account.  I've eliminated that as a possible cause first.